# Can I set an object variable with a reflection value to a property of another object?

Tags: kotlin

I have a class that has a property whose type is KMutableVar1. The objects of that class have a variable assigned to a reflection of another class's property. I have a function that is supposed take in an object of the first class and uses its variable of type KMutableVar1 to determine which property of an object of the second class to edit.

jeez that paragraph is awful im so so sorry ><

I have already tried assigning the object's KMutableVar1 variable to another variable and then trying to tie that variable to an object using dot notation, but that variable name isn't in the primary constructor for the class and thus  an error occurs.

```
class Thing(var amount: Int, var id: Int){
     fun editAttributes(object: Thing, editor: RemoteEdit){
          //My initial thought here was to do the following:
          var editing = editor.attributeToEdit
          object.editing = editor.newValue
          //But this raises an error since class 'thing' has no attribute 'editing'
     }
}

var bananas = Thing(amount = 12, id = 21)

class RemoteEdit(var attributeToEdit: KMutableVar1, var newValue: Int)

var remoteEditor = RemoteEdit(attributeToEdit = Thing::amount, newValue = 23)
```

My intent is for the function to change `bananas.amount` to 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not fully understanding why you need it but it will work I guess:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty1

class Thing(var amount: Int, var id: Int) {
    fun editAttributes(editor: RemoteEdit) {
        val editing = editor.attributeToEdit
        editing.set(this, editor.newValue)
    }
}

class RemoteEdit(var attributeToEdit: KMutableProperty1<Thing, Int>, var newValue: Int)

fun main() {
    val bananas = Thing(amount = 12, id = 21)
    val remoteEditor = RemoteEdit(attributeToEdit = Thing::amount, newValue = 23)
    bananas.editAttributes(remoteEditor)
    println(bananas.amount) // prints 23
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this might be an XY problem because there are so many unusual things going on in your code. Why would the implementation of changing the property value through reflection be in the class that's being edited?

I suppose if there is some reason you need to be able to pass these parameters for editing around, you would need a class, but then it makes sense for it to implement the function for using it by itself:

```
class RemoteEdit<T, R>(var attributeToEdit: KMutableProperty1<T, R>, var newValue: R) {
    fun execute(item: T) {
        attributeToEdit.set(item, newValue)
    }
}

val bananas = Thing(amount = 12, id = 21)
val edit23 = RemoteEdit(Thing::amount, 23)
edit23.execute(bananas)
```

If you don't need to pass these around, all you need is a top level function:

```
fun <T, R> editProperty(item: T, attributeToEdit: KMutableProperty1<T, R>, newValue: R) =
    attributeToEdit.set(item, newValue)

val bananas = Thing(amount = 12, id = 21)
editProperty(bananas, Thing::amount, 23)
```